# NullPointerException when implementing custom row layout

Tags: android, listview, nullpointerexception

This is my java class that is storing news in array of a class news and then output them in listview

```
public class News extends Activity {

List<news> myNews = new ArrayList<news>();



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(com.example.makkosarka.R.layout.activity_news);

    populateNewsList();
    populateListView();
}

private void populateListView() {
    ArrayAdapter<news> adapter = new MyListAdapter();
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(com.example.makkosarka.R.id.listview_news);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

 }
public void populateNewsList() {
            //tuka ja polnis listata
                   myNews.add(new news("title1", 1,"something1"));
                   myNews.add(new news("title2", 2,"something2"));
                   myNews.add(new news("title3", 3,"something3"));

    }

 private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<news>{
     public MyListAdapter(){
            super(News.this,com.example.makkosarka.R.layout.item_news, myNews);
     }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    //make sure that we have a View to work with        
    View row = convertView;
    if (row == null){
            row = getLayoutInflater().inflate(com.example.makkosarka.R.layout.item_news, parent,false);
        }

     //Find the product to work with
    news currentNews = myNews.get(position);

     //Fill the view

    TextView txtcena = (TextView)findViewById(com.example.makkosarka.R.id.item_txtCena);

    TextView txtime = (TextView)findViewById(com.example.makkosarka.R.id.item_txtName);

    txtime.setText((currentNews).getBody());
    txtcena.setText(( currentNews).getTitle());      


            return row;               
     }
 }

private class news{
    private String Title;
    private int ImageID;
    private String Body;


    public news(String title, int imageID, String body){
            this.Title=title;
            this.ImageID=imageID;
            this.Body=body;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
            return Title;
    }

    public int getImageID() {
            return ImageID;
    }

    public String getBody() {
            return Body;
    }}}
```

The error nullpointerexception acour at the line:

```
    txtime.setText((currentNews).getBody());
    txtcena.setText(( currentNews).getTitle());
```

What could be the problem with this structure of the code?
I'm implementing custom row layout!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change to

```
TextView txtcena = (TextView)row.findViewById(com.example.makkosarka.R.id.item_txtCena);
TextView txtime = (TextView)row.findViewById(com.example.makkosarka.R.id.item_txtName);
```

The views belong to the inflated layout.

Consider using `ViewHolder`.

```
class ViewHolder
{
     TextView txtcena,txtime;
}

 @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null){
            holder = new VieHolder(); 
            convertVIew = getLayoutInflater().inflate(com.example.makkosarka.R.layout.item_news, parent,false);
            holder.txtcena = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(com.example.makkosarka.R.id.item_txtCena);
            holder.txtime = (TextView)convertVIew.findViewById(com.example.makkosarka.R.id.item_txtName); 
            convertView.setTag(holder); 

        } else{
              holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }
      news currentNews = myNews.get(position);
      holder.txtime.setText((currentNews).getBody());
      holder.txtcena.setText(( currentNews).getTitle());      


            return convertView;               
     }
```

Comment: can you describe why using `ViewHolder`?

Comment: @Shayanpourvatan http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

Answer (score 1):

As you are accessing another view items in to the listview you should find the id from that view so change like this

```
TextView txtcena = (TextView)row.findViewById(com.example.makkosarka.R.id.item_txtCena);
TextView txtime = (TextView)row.findViewById(com.example.makkosarka.R.id.item_txtName);
```